# Namespace of Regex won't work

Tags: c#, .net

Im refurbishing some old code that used to work on .NET Framework 3.5 to make it work on .NET Framework 4 using C#.

The following Regex used to work fine with version 3.5 but doesn't work anymore for some strange reason.

```
public static readonly Regex ChatColorRegex = new Regex("\\|c[A-Za-z0-9]{6,8}"),
                                 ChatLinkRegex = new Regex("\\|H.*?\\|h");
```

I have added the 'using System.Text.RegularExpressions' at the top of my file, but the following error rises: 'The type or namespace RegularExpressions does not exist in the namespace System.Text.

I've googled about that and read that you have to add a Reference to System.Text.RegularExpressions in Visual Studio. However, when i did, i couldn't find System.Text.RegularExpressions in the list of References i could add.

I'm using Visual Studio 2012.

Could anyone tell me what im doing wrong, or forget to read?

Comment: What framework version are you targeting?

Comment: I'm targeting .NET Framework 4 in the project's properties. It was at 4.5, changing it to 4 didn't change anything (even after closing/reopening the solution).

Comment: Can you even manually enter System.Text.RegularExpressions?

Comment: There is no assembly named `System.Text.RegularExpressions` and you cannot add a reference to it. As have been pointed out in an answer the `Regex` class is in the `System` assembly in .NET 4.

Comment: @Blam: I'm not talking to you as I don't understand your comment about "manually entering" something. However, I wanted to make sure that anyone reading this question didn't go looking for an non-existent assembly.

Comment: @MartinLiversage I meant not using the using and enter the full path in the code behind.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Regex class is still in the System.Text.RegularExpression namespace.  The class is in the System assembly.

If you check your project references in Solution Explorer, you should see a reference to the System assembly.  Check the properties of that reference to see what .NET Framework version is being used for the System assembly reference.  It should match the .NET Framework version you selected for the "Target framework" in the project properties (Application tab).

**Edit: The Regex class is in the System.Text.RegularExpressions namespace, not System.Text.**

Comment: No, `Regex` is in the `System.Text.RegularExpressions` namespace, not `System.Text. You're right about the assembly part, of course.

Comment: There is a `System.Text.RegularExpressions` DLL also which we can obtain via [System.Text.RegularExpressions](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Text.RegularExpressions/) nuget package. I've no idea why this DLL is there when all the regular expression related classes already exist in `System.dll`.