# C# Missing Reference

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

When running this code:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace WebAutomationDemo
{
 public class ExtractDigitsFromString
 {
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string inputData = "No 38, Bunder Garden Street, Perambur,   Chennai - 600011";
        var data = Regex.Match(inputData, "/s([a - z][A - Z]) +/s -/s/d[6]").Value;
        Console.WriteLine(data);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
  }
}
```

I get the following error:

> The type or namespace name '`RegularExpressions`' does not exist in the namespace '`System.Text`' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

This happens even after referencing `System.Text.RegularExpressions` assembly.

Comment: even after referencing System.Text.RegularExpressions assembly im facing the above problem plz suggest me

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13322798/namespace-of-regex-wont-work

Comment: Add System reference in your project.

Comment: There is no such assembly called `System.Text.RegularExpressions` so you could not have referenced it.  Perhaps you meant that you tried to import the `System.Text.RegularExpressions` _namespace_?

Comment: Possible duplicate (?) as @ViniciusGonçalves pointed it out.

Answer (score 0):

Are you still facing the same error,may be your assembly System is missing RegularExpressions method as stated by many.

Goto Object browser i.e click on any project solutions's references(expand) open any assembly will take it to take object browser window.

Now check whether the System.Text contains the RegualrExpressions method.

[Object browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g8fpp.png)

If you follow the link there is an image of my object browser that do contains System.Text.RegularExpressions assembly.

If its missing ,download a valid assembly from MSDN

Below is one of link for a System.dll,download it or google it you can downlaod it easily.
https://www.dllme.com/dll/files/system_dll.html
Then goto references of your project and then add the downloaded assembly.

Comment: im not able to find system.text in my object browser so plz help me in, how to download assembly and install.

Comment: Did you try to navigate to assembly from the namespace clicking on f12 ..what was the result ?It should redirect you to static method of the assembly